# Android7ではSet-Cookieが動作するがAndroid10では動作しない

Tags: android, http, cookie

こんにちは。AndroidとOkhttp3についての質問です。

Okhttp3（3.10.0）と[PersistentCookieStore](https://gist.github.com/franmontiel/ed12a2295566b7076161)を用いてセッションログインを実装しているのですが、Android7では問題なくログインできるのですがAndroid10ではログインできません。（[ログイン先](https://x.mirm.jp/login)がOSによって違う動作をさせるということはありません。）

通信内容をStethoを用いて調べてみると、タイトルの通りHttpヘッダのSet-CookieがAndroid10では動いていなかったようです。（※Android7および通常のJRE 11ではSet-Cookieが動作してCookieとして返し、正しくログインできました。）
以下に周辺のコードと通信のデバッグ内容を記載します。どなたか原因及び解決法のご教示をお願いいたします。

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
minSdkVersion 22
targetSdkVersion 29
```

```
// 便宜上loginを実行する関数
fun loginTest() {
    API.login("serverId", "my_password")
}
```

```
object API {
    private val gson = Gson()
    var loggedIn = false
    var serverId = ""

    // LoginResponseおよびAbstractResponseはレスポンスのデータクラス
    fun login(serverId: String, password: String): LoginResponse {
        try {
            val response = Http.postXWwwFormUrlEncoded(
                "https://x.mirm.jp/authenticate", mapOf(
                    "serverId" to URLEncoder.encode(serverId),
                    "password" to URLEncoder.encode(password),
                    "_csrf" to getCsrf() // ログインのため一度CSRFトークンを取得する
                )
            ) ?: return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_ERROR, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_FAILED)

            if (response.contains("期限切れでサーバーが削除されました。")) return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_SUCCEEDED, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_DELETED_SERVER)
            if (response.contains("サーバー削除ボタンによって削除されています。")) return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_SUCCEEDED, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_USER_DELETED)

            return response.contains("MiRm | コントロールパネル").let {
                if (it) {
                    this.loggedIn = true
                    this.serverId = serverId
                    return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_SUCCEEDED, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_SUCCEEDED)

                } else {
                    return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_SUCCEEDED, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_FAILED)
                }
            }

        } catch (e: MissingRequestException) {
            if (e.errorCode == 503) {
                return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_OUT_OF_SERVICE, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_FAILED)
            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return LoginResponse(AbstractResponse.STATUS_ERROR, LoginResponse.LOGIN_STATUS_FAILED)
    }

    private fun getCsrf(): String {
        val document = Jsoup.parse(Http.get("https://x.mirm.jp/login"))
        return document.select("input[name=_csrf]").attr("value") // CSRFトークンを返す
    }
}
```

```
object Http {

    private const val USER_AGENT = "MiRmGo/0.0.1"
    private val client: OkHttpClient
    private val headers: Headers

    init {
        val cookieHandler = CookieManager(PersistentCookieStore(MyApplication.getApplication()), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL)

        client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
            .addNetworkInterceptor(StethoInterceptor())
            .build()

        headers = Headers.Builder()
            .set("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8")
            .set("User-agent", USER_AGENT)
            .set("Accept-Language", "ja,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8")
            .set("Connection", "keep-alive")
            .set("Referer", "https://x.mirm.jp/login")
            .set("Origin", "https://x.mirm.jp")
            .build()
    }

    fun postXWwwFormUrlEncoded(url: String, data: Map<String, String>): String? {
        val postData = data.let {
            var str = ""
            it.forEach {
                str += "${it.key}=${URLEncoder.encode(it.value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())}&"
            }
            str.removeSuffix("&")
        }

        val requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), postData)
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .headers(headers)
            .header("Content-Length", postData.length.toString())
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .post(requestBody)
            .build()
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        if (!response.isSuccessful) throw MissingRequestException(response.code())
        return response.body()?.string()
    }

    fun get(url: String, data: Map<String, String> = mapOf()): String? {
        var postUrl = url

        if (data.isNotEmpty()) {
            postUrl += "?"
            data.forEach {
                postUrl += "${it.key}=${it.value}&"
            }
            postUrl = postUrl.removeSuffix("&")
        }

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(postUrl)
            .headers(headers)
            .build()
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

        if (!response.isSuccessful) throw MissingRequestException(response.code())
        return response.body()?.string()
    }
}
```

Android7 /login
[image: Android7 /login]

Android7 /authenticate
[image: Android7 /authenticate]

Android10 /login
[image: Android10 /login]

Android10 /authenticate
[image: Android10 /authenticate]

Answer (score 1):

`Set-Cookie: (...) ; HttpOnly` 核心はこれでしょうね。

Android 9 (API28) から HTTP はデフォルトで無効化されます。[公式：フレームワーク セキュリティの変更](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28?hl=ja#framework-security-changes)

従って、

1. サーバー側の動作仕様を、HttpOnly の Cookie に依存しないように修正する

または

2. クライアントアプリ（Android 9 以上）側では、デフォルトの動作を変更して、「[公式：アプリで特定のドメインのクリアテキストを有効にする](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=ja)」要するに、特定サイトに対して例外的に HTTP を許可する

必要があります。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。1および2の両方を設定してx.mirm.jpを許可する設定にして再度試しましたが、変化がありませんでした。

Comment: @Itsu これ以上のことは私にはわかりません。そもそもスクリーンショットを見るかぎり、Android7のLogin（一枚目の画像）では既に元からcookieがセットされているようにも思えるのですが。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございました。確かにもともとcookieがセットされていますが、消去してテストしても結果は変わりませんでした。

Comment: Okhttp3を使わず、HttpURLConnectionを用いて通信部分を実装することで解決しました。ありがとうございました。